# Is this an AngularJS service masquerading as a factory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http, angularjs-service

I created an AngularJS factory that I reuse for data access:

```
app.factory('abstractFactory3', function ($http) {
 
    function abstractFactory3(odataUrlBase) {
        this.odataUrlBase = odataUrlBase;
    }
 
    abstractFactory3.prototype = {
        getList: function (odataOptions) {
            return $http.get(this.odataUrlBase, {
                params: odataOptions
            });
        },
        get: function (id, odataOptions) {
            return $http.get(this.odataUrlBase + '/' + id, {
                params: odataOptions
            });
        },
        insert: function (data) {
            return $http.post(this.odataUrlBase, data);
        },
        update: function (id, data) {
            return $http.put(this.odataUrlBase + '(' + id + ')', data);
        },
        remove: function (id) {
            return $http.delete(this.odataUrlBase + '(' + id + ')');
        }
    };
 
    return abstractFactory3;
});
```

Reading a brief write-up on the [differences between Angular services, factories and providers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666049/172359), I am a bit confused as to what this *factory* actually is, based on those definitions.

In Summary:

> **Services**: provided with an instance of the function.
>
> **Factories**: the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory.
>
> **Providers**: provided with ProviderFunction().$get(). The constructor function is instantiated before the $get method is called

To use this factory, it is initialized with an ODada path:

```
var dataFactory = new abstractFactory3("/odata/ContentType");
dataFactory.getList(odataParams)
.success(function (result) {
    options.success(result);
})
.error (function (error) {
    console.log("data error");
});
```

Since I'm newing up the `abstractFactory3`, I am now provided with an instance of the function (like a service)... Initialization provides me with an instance of the function - service, right?  However, a value is returned by calling a method - `.get(), .getList(), .insert(), .update(), .remove()`.  Is considered to be similar to a provider's `ProviderFunction().$get()`?

Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providers, factories, services, seems more complex than it actually each. Each is a specialized version of the other allowing you to accomplish the same thing with less code, if it meets your need.

For example if all you are returning is a literally value like a number or a string you can use value and accomplish that in one line of code. You can also go up the chain and do it using a factory, but you would be writing less code.

On the other hand if wanted to calculate a value based on another value that you get from the server. Well you can't do that using value therefore you have to go one level up to a factory.

So on and so on up the chain. The following blog post goes into that in detail and gives you several examples:

http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2015/11/the-difference-between-service-provider-and-factory-in-angularjs/

Here is a high level image from that same post illustrating what I said above:

[image: Providers, services, factories are all the same in AngularJS]

Answer (score 3):

Factories return the result of invoking the function - in your case, its just a function.  So, when the factory is injected, it is also just a function. That is why you can 'new' up your function after it has been injected (like in your example). You are correct, this is essentially what a service is.

No, a provider.$get is not similar to calling .getList(), .insert(), etc. The result of provider.$get is what is injected by the $injector.  For factories, it is the result of invoking the factory function.  For services, it is the result of new'ing up the service's constructor function.

Provider.$get is more flexible - it can return whatever you want (which means you can inject whatever you want).